# How do I round this binary number to the nearest even

Tags: binary, floating-point

I have this binary representation of `0.1`:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

I need to round it to the nearest even to be able to store it in the double precision floating point. I can't seem to understand how to do that. Most tutorials talk about guard, round and sticky bits - where are they in this representation?

Also I've found the following explanation:

> Let’s see what 0.1 looks like in double-precision. First, let’s write
>   it in binary, truncated to 57 significant bits:

```
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001…
```

> Bits 54 and beyond total to greater than half the value of bit
>   position 53, so this rounds up to

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

This one doesn't talk about GRS bits, why? Aren't they always required?

Comment: "round it to the nearest even"??? The nearest even is $0$, is that really what you want?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37106456/2545680) is where my question originates from, the author says that _You round (to "nearest even") to the number of bits in your floating-point format. _